# Unable to Loop Over Nested Dictionary in Stored Procedure: Psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, psycopg2

I'm trying to add the values of a nested dictionary within a list to a table using a stored procedure in `psycopg2`. This is the schema I receive from a JSON application:

```
[
    {
        "team_id": 236,
        "lineup": [
            {
                "player_id": 3043,
                "country": {
                    "id": 61,
                    "name": "Denmark"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "team_id": 237,
        "lineup": [
            {
                "player_id": 3045,
                "country": {
                    "id": 62,
                    "name": "Italy"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to add the player's `country` into a table in Postgres. The `id` will be of type integer and `name` of type `VARCHAR`. Here is my stored procedure:

```
'''
    CREATE PROCEDURE insert_country_by_lineups(data JSON)
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        FOR team IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(data) LOOP
            FOR player in SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(team->'lineup') LOOP
                INSERT INTO country(id,name) 
                VALUES (CAST(player->'country'->>'id' AS integer), player->'country'->>'name')
                ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id;
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP; 
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    '''
```

However, I keep getting this when I execute the procedure on my cursor:

```
loop variable of loop over rows must be a record variable or list of scalar variables
LINE 5:         FOR team IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(data...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not reading the error message: `loop variable of loop over rows must be a record variable ...` or the docs [Loop over query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING): `The target is a record variable, row variable, or comma-separated list of scalar variables.`. You have not declared any such variable.

Comment: I’m not sure how to do that, is it just DECLARE team as JSON?

Comment: Yes, but then you are going to run into error at `FOR player in SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(team->'lineup') ...` as `team` will be a JSON object not an array and `player` is not declared. Seems to me better to do this in the Python code using the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module to turn the JSON in a `list` of `dicts` and pull the `id` and `name` from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module to get country `id` and `name`. Then use `psycopg2` to `INSERT` into `country` table.

```
import json
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres', port=5432)
cur = con.cursor()

j = """[
    {
        "team_id": 236,
        "lineup": [
            {
                "player_id": 3043,
                "country": {
                    "id": 61,
                    "name": "Denmark"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "team_id": 237,
        "lineup": [
            {
                "player_id": 3045,
                "country": {
                    "id": 62,
                    "name": "Italy"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]"""

player_list = json.loads(j)
player_list
[{'team_id': 236,
  'lineup': [{'player_id': 3043, 'country': {'id': 61, 'name': 'Denmark'}}]},
 {'team_id': 237,
  'lineup': [{'player_id': 3045, 'country': {'id': 62, 'name': 'Italy'}}]}]

for row in player_list:
    country = row['lineup'][0]['country']
    id, name = country['id'], country['name']
    print(id, name)
    cur.execute('insert into country(id, name) values(%s, %s)', [id, name])
61 Denmark
62 Italy

con.commit()
cur.execute('select * from country')
cur.fetchall()
 [(61, 'Denmark'), (62, 'Italy')]
```